# OrientDB update query throwing exception while removing list references (rowid's)

Tags: sql, orientdb

```
UPDATE Student REMOVE couses = #25:183
```

Student is a class which contains couses field of List type. There is another table Cousre which is having course data.

When I try to remove course rowid reference from Student table, the following error is thrown:

> Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument '75' is not a RecordId in form of string. Format must be: cluster-id:cluster-position

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? Do you want to remove the field couses for the vertex Student?

Comment: i  have found duplicate entries in course table with different timestamps. So i'm deleting the duplicate entries programmatically and also removing references from Student table.

Comment: the orientdb version is 1.0.1 and using Object Model

Answer (score 0):

Generally if we perform any update operation it should return greater than 0 value if query matched or simply 0(in not found case). this working well for some records and doesn't for some. this might be the bug in orientdb.

One way to handle this is perform select with particular rowid if found record then only do update.